# Laravel: Dynamic tabs don't show the correct data?

Tags: php, html, laravel, tabs

I am trying to use dynamic tabs in laravel and iam kinda new to it. Iam stuck in it for like 2 days.

I have two variables that getting data from tables in mysql.

```
$stations = Station::select('id', 'name')->get();
// return $staions;

$queues = Queue::withTrashed()
                ->oldest()
                ->get();
// return $queues;
```

The data in `$schedules`:

```
 [
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"siinay"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "name":"jigjiga"
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "name":"Idaacada"
   },
   {
      "id":4,
      "name":"Xero Awr"
   }
 ]
```

And the data in the `$queues`:

[image]

So the **problem** is here in dynmaic tabs: I have wanted to display station names in the **nav-tabs** and queues in the **tab-content**. So i did it like this.

```
<ul  class="nav nav-tabs">
     @forelse ($stations as $station)
             <li >
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-{{ $station->id }}"  >
                        {!! $station->name !!}
                  </a>
             </li>
      @empty

      @endforelse
</ul>

<div style="margin-top: 15%"  class="tab-content">
     @foreach($queues as $queue)
           @if($queue)
                 <div id="tab-{{ $queue->station_id}}" class="tab-pane fade">
                        <p>{!! $queue->bus_number !!}</p>
                 </div>
            @else
                  <div>empty</div>
           @endif
    @endforeach
</div>
```

when i run the above code, `it only showing the last queue bus_number` per each sttions. every  stations queue

Answer (score 0):

Oldest is indeed the oldest, it's the opposite to first. Try this to get a collection:

```
$queues = Queue::withTrashed()
                ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                ->get();
```

In the view (simplified):

```
<ul  class="nav nav-tabs">
     @foreach ($stations as $station)
             <li>
                  <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-{{ $station->id }}">
                        {{ $station->name }}
                  </a>
             </li>
      @endforeach
</ul>

<div style="margin-top: 15%"  class="tab-content">
     @foreach($queues as $queue)
             <div id="tab-{{ $queue->station_id }}" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <p>{{ $queue->bus_number }}</p>
             </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

No need to check for empty. Each one is a table record. Unless you want to check on bus_number or station_id.

Comment: as the image above is showing i'm getting correct data from the controller, but i think the problem is in the **View**  `tabs`,

Comment: I'll rewrite your code, check it and see what happens.

Comment: i check that out, but it's the same. from the look of it it just looping in the first then exist. thats why it's showing bus_number per station.